# Stuck with python click bot

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want my code close website after click and open it again and do it process again . However, I get stuck with loop, here is my code, where should I add while ?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time


browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

browser.get('https://www.targetsite.com/')

time.sleep(6)

button = browser.find_element_by_name('Products')
button.click()

time.sleep(5)


browser.close()
```

Comment: What actual problem is? If you want to do it in infinite loop, just add `while True:` before `browser = webdr...` and add indents to all rows after `while`

Comment: I want my code open browser and click target button then close the website and open it again do the same process. I tried while but my code is crash.

Comment: what is crash error?